# Can eigenvectors of a symmetric circulant matrix be real?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, fourier-analysis

Since eigenvectors of a symmetric circulant matrix are related to the Fourier basis, I expect that they are complex.
But I do not find such statement in mathematical books, and so I think my supposition is wrong.

Can you help me to understand the correct reasoning?

Comment: The identiy matrix is circulant symmetric.

Comment: They must be real.

Comment: Thanks. But it does not match to the fact that eigenvectors of a symmetric circulant matrix are related to the Fourier basis.

Comment: This is true in the generic case, but when you have a matrix with repeated eigenvalues then one could have a linear combination of eigenvectors which is real-valued.  Since the eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix are real, this necessarily happens — I imagine they combine in conjugate pairs.

Comment: @Alessandro Whenever you have an eigenspace of dimension $\ge 2$ there are many ways to choose a basis of eigenvectors.  Just because the Fourier modes work for all circulant matrices doesn't mean that some circulants can't have real eigenvectors.

Comment: @ErickWong Thanks for your explanation. Is there a link between real eigenvectors and the sine and cosine coefficients of the Fourier representation?

Comment: Yes, you can write the eigenvectors as 
$(1, \cos (2\pi j/n), \cos (2\pi 2j/n), \dots, \cos (2\pi (n-1)j/n))$ and $(0, \sin (2\pi j/n), \sin (2\pi 2j/n), \dots, \sin (2\pi (n-1)j/n))$. It's quite the same as expressing $2\cos(\theta) = e^{i \theta} + e^{-i \theta}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, the eigenvalues and thus eigenvectors of  whatever symmetric real matrix are real. That the matrix happens to be circulant does not change this. But let's go through it for circulant specifically:

The eigenvalues of a circulant matrix (with first row $(c_0, \dots, c_{n-1})$) are given by (see [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix))

$$\lambda(w)=c_0 +c_1 w + c_2 w^2 + \dots +   c_{n-1} w^{n-1}$$
where $w$ is some $n$-th root of unity.

For the matrix to be symmetric one needs $c_{n-i} = c_i$.
One can then rewrite 
$$c_i w^i  + c_{n-i} w^{n-i}= 2c_i \Re(w^i).$$
Thus for odd $n$ one gets:
$$c_0 +  2c_1 \Re w + 2c_2\Re w^2 +   \dots +   2c_{(n-1)/2} \Re(w^{(n-1)/2})$$
which is always real (assuming a real matrix of course).
And for even $n$ one gets 
$$c_0 + c_{n/2}w^{n/2} + 2c_1 \Re w + 2c_2\Re w^2 +   \dots +   2c_{(n-1)/2} \Re(w^{(n-2)/2})$$
which is also always real as $w^{n/2}$ is $\pm 1$.

The eigenvectors then can also be chosen to be real.

Let me further add that while $(1, w , \dots, w^{n-1})$ is always an eigenvector for the eigenvector $\lambda(w)$, as explained on the site above. One has  $\lambda(w)= \lambda(w^{-1})$  so that one has the eigenvectors $(1, w , \dots, w^{n-1})$  and $(1, w^{-1} , \dots, w^{-(n-1)})$. The sum of the two, twice the real part, is then a real eigenvector (same for the imaginary part).

Comment: How does one arrive at the conclusion that $(1,\omega^{-1},\ldots,\omega^{-(n-1)})$ is also an eigenvector from $\lambda(\omega)=\lambda(\omega^{-1})$? And also later that $2Re[(1,\ldots,\omega^{n-1})+(1,\ldots,\omega^{-(n-1)})]$?